# Plot less points (line plot) for matplot lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Currently I have a plot with too many points, I want to avoid overlapping. Want to know how to reduce the amount of points in order to have a smoother line.

## Plot Code

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (18,10)) # Figure size in inches (size_x, size_y)
ax = plt.axes()
min_val = prediction_intervals2[:, 0]
max_val = prediction_intervals2[:, 1]
true_values = y_test
predicted_values = PLS_Model1.predict(X_test)
plt.plot(min_val, label = "Min", color='blue')
plt.plot(max_val, label = "Max", color='red')
plt.plot(true_values, label = "y", color = "black")
plt.plot(predicted_values, label = "y\u0302", marker='o')
plt.title('Conformal Predictor Final Predictions')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

## Current Plot

[image]

## Desired Plot

Plot that I want

[image]

Comment: use a numpy slice to plot every, say, 5th point. For example: `plt.plot(true_values[::5], ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to revise my code properly and came to the desired output by just selecting less data points, quite simple. Posted the answer just in case.

```
min_val_normal = plot_normalized_table[['Min']]
max_val_normal = plot_normalized_table[['Max']]
original_normal = plot_normalized_table[['Original Label']]
interval_normal = plot_normalized_table[['Interval Size']]
normal_predicted = predicted_values[0:50]
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (18,10)) # Figure size in inches (size_x, size_y)
ax = plt.axes()
#predicted_values = PLS_Model1.predict(X_test) #Predictions from test data (run at least once for the plot to work)
plt.plot(min_val_normal, label = "Min", color='blue')
plt.plot(max_val_normal, label = "Max", color='red')
plt.plot(original_normal, label = "y", color = "black")
plt.plot(normal_predicted, label = "y\u0302", marker='o', )
plt.title('Normalized Final Conformal Predictions')
plt.xlim([-1, 51])
plt.ylim([-1, 2])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]